How to make pagination in aiogram 3.5?
I would like to make pagination for my inline-menu in a telegram bot so that the “back” button returns to the previous menu, but I don’t know how to do this other than making a separate handler for each “back” button. I would be grateful if you give me an example of correct pagination. Thanks to everyone.
def menu_1():
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="button 1",callback_data='b_1'))
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="button 2", callback_data='b_2'))
    keyboard.adjust(2)
    return keyboard.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True)


def menu_2():
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="button 3", callback_data='b_3'))
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="button 4", callback_data='b_4'))
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="back", callback_data='back_to_menu_1'))
    keyboard.adjust(2, 1)
    return keyboard.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True)


def menu_3():
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="button 5",callback_data='b_5'))
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="button 6",callback_data='b_6'))
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text="back", callback_data='back_to_menu_2'))
    keyboard.adjust(2, 1)
    return keyboard.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True)

@user_router_inline.callback_query(F.data == 'back_to_menu_1')
async def configuration_channel_captions(callback: types.CallbackQuery):

    await callback.message.edit_text(text="this is menu number 1",
                                     reply_markup=menu_1())
    await callback.answer()


@user_router_inline.callback_query(F.data == 'back_to_menu_2')
async def configuration_channel_captions(callback: types.CallbackQuery):

    await callback.message.edit_text(text="this is menu number 2",
                                     reply_markup=menu_2())
    await callback.answer()


An example https://github.com/MasterGroosha/aiogram-3-guide/blob/master/code/08_inline_mode/handlers/inline_pagination_demo.py
